# How to evaluate once a makefile conditional variable?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to use the same value to all tasks, but the variable are evaluating for every task. How to avoid it?

Version: GNU Make 4.1

Makefile content:

```
SHELL = /bin/bash -ex
BUILD_TIMESTAMP ?= $(shell date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
VERSION ?= 1.2-${BUILD_TIMESTAMP}

t1:
    echo ${VERSION}
    sleep 1

t2:
    echo ${VERSION}
    sleep 1
```

Output:

```
$ make t1 t2
date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S
echo 1.2-20170803143838
+ echo 1.2-20170803143838
1.2-20170803143838
sleep 1
+ sleep 1
+ date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S
echo 1.2-20170803143839
+ echo 1.2-20170803143839
1.2-20170803143839
sleep 1
+ sleep 1
```

Answer (score 7):

The `?=` in *GNU make* is equivalent to a `=` that's only done when the variable was undefined before. As you *may* know, `=` sets a *recursively expanded variable*, that is, its value is only expanded when the variable itself is expanded.

What you want instead is a *simply expanded variable*, its content is only expanded once and directly assigned to it. For more info on the difference, see [The Two Flavors of Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html). You get a *simply expanded variable* by assigning it with `:=`.

You have two options to solve your immediate problem:

1. Make `BUILD_TIMESTAMP` a *simply expanded* variable by reassigning it:

   ```
   BUILD_TIMESTAMP ?= $(shell date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
   BUILD_TIMESTAMP := ${BUILD_TIMESTAMP}

   VERSION ?= 1.2-${BUILD_TIMESTAMP}
   ```
2. Do the logic for only assigning when the variable was undefined yourself:

   ```
   ifeq ($(origin BUILD_TIMESTAMP), undefined)
   BUILD_TIMESTAMP := $(shell date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
   endif

   VERSION ?= 1.2-${BUILD_TIMESTAMP}
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Just add the following statements to your code after corresponding `?=` assignments:

```
BUILD_TIMESTAMP := $(BUILD_TIMESTAMP)
VERSION := $(VERSION)
```